# O que "pesar o cabelo" significa exactamente?

Tags: significado-em-contexto

Pesar o cabelo significa pressioná-lo fisicamente (e assim o cabelo fica com pouco volume) ou significa danificá-lo/fazé-lo sofrer?

Contexto:
TWIST SHAMPOO – Linha NT Curly Home Care. Shampoo para cabelos cacheados, que promove a limpeza sem danificá-los. Cuida das áreas mais danificadas sem pesar, deixando os fios mais macios, tratados e saudáveis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O significado é exatamente o que o sentido da palavra, o seja que não deixa o cabelo pesado. Mantendo aquele cabelo leve "aquele que qualquer ventinho já esvoaça todo"